# How to redefine private method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create component from Trumbowyg plugin to vue.js library. I need add  two way binding in this beautiful wysiwyg editor.
How to rewrite buildEditor() method?
This method is private. how to do it correctly?

```
<script>
jQuery.trumbowyg = {
    // options object
};

(function (navigator, window, document, $, undefined) {

    $.fn.trumbowyg = function (options, params) {
        // ... code ...
        $(this).data('trumbowyg', new Trumbowyg(this, options));
        // ... code ...
    };

    var Trumbowyg = function (editorElem, o) {
        var t = this;
        // ... code ...
        t.init();
    };

    Trumbowyg.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var t = this;

            t.buildEditor();
            // ... code ...
        },

        buildEditor: function () {
            // i need rewrite this method
        }
        // code for otner method

    };
})(navigator, window, document, jQuery);

// -------------------------------------
// other file. I want init this plugin

// here do need to rewrite buildEditor() method? What best way to do this?
```

$('.selector').trumbowyg();

Comment: What do you mean by rewrite it correctly? What is it that you expect it to do? Really hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I need add some code in buildEditor method. "Correctly"- it means not change code in source file(npm module), only on my code, not npm package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this plugin doesn't return 'Trumbowyg' variable it's not possible. I recommend fork this plugin and create your own version with your settings.

Answer (score 1):

The *best* way to do it would be to fork the plugin yourself, [as Slava answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236911/4633828). But *technically* you're able to modify that function.

Whenever you construct a class, that instance has its own [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) property. This is equal to the class function.

So, if you can get access to an instance of `Trumbowyg`, you're able to use its class:

```
$foo.trumbowyg(...)
var trumbowyg = $foo.data('trumbowyg')
var TrumbowygClass = trumbowyg.constructor
```

Now we can modify its prototype:

```
TrumbowygClass.prototype.buildEditor = function() {
  // ...
}
```

You might want to make `$foo` be a temporary or unused element. That's because it'll have called the old `buildEditor` (as soon as you ran `$foo.trumbowyg()`), not your own modified version.

After you've set the prototype function you could run it on the element you actually want to use `trumbowyg` on (e.g. `$('#target')`)

As an example:

```js
(function() {
  window.makeInstance = function() {
    return new HiddenClass()
  }

  var HiddenClass = function() {
    this.setGreeting()
    this.showGreeting()
  }

  HiddenClass.prototype.setGreeting = function() {
    this.greeting = 'Hello, world!'
  }

  HiddenClass.prototype.showGreeting = function() {
    console.log(this.greeting)
  }
})()

var myTempInstance = makeInstance()
// Should log 'Hello, world!'

var HiddenClass = myTempInstance.constructor
console.log(HiddenClass) // Should be the HiddenClass function

// Now we overwrite our function..
HiddenClass.prototype.setGreeting = function() {
  this.greeting = 'Redefined!'
}

var myUsedInstance = makeInstance()
// Should log 'Redefined!', since we redefined setGreeting

// And later we can use `myUsedInstance`.
// In this code myTempInstance is like $foo, and myUsedInstance
// is like $('#target').
```